# I am having login page how to authenticate the user using coredata database?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I had created a login page and registration page and saved the registered data in core data database but now I need to authenticate the user so that in order to move to another view controller.

**here is my code ....**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var registerButton: UIButton!
var accounts = [Account]()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getAccountData()
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
    registerButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
    usernameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    usernameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray .cgColor;
    usernameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    usernameTextField.setValue(UIColor.lightGray, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor");
    passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor;
    passwordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    passwordTextField.setValue(UIColor.lightGray, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender: nil)
    return
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    _ = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
}

@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if (usernameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! == true
    {
        let usernamealert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter username", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        usernamealert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(usernamealert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! == true {
            let passwordalert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            passwordalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(passwordalert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Account")
    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        if results.count > 0
        {
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
            {
                if let firstname = result.value(forKey: "firstName") as? String
                {
                    if(usernameTextField.text == firstname)
                    {
                        if let password = result.value(forKey: "lastname") as? String
                        {
                            if(passwordTextField.text == password)
                            {

                            }else{
                                let passwordalert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Wrong password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                passwordalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                                self.present(passwordalert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func unwindToView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){}
func getAccountData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        accounts = try context.fetch(Account.fetchRequest())
    } catch  {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, What is the issue you are facing, Kindly explain the question, Kindly read how to ask questions on this site, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this
call this method from viewWillAppear

```
self.getAccountData()
```

and put below code in loginButton() method After the validation done

```
 var username = ""
 var passString = ""
 var checkRecord = false
 for item in accounts
 {
    username = item.value(forKeyPath: "firstName") as! String
    passString = item.value(forKeyPath: "lastname") as! String
    if username == usernameTextField.text && passwordTextField.text == passString
    {
         checkRecord = true;
    }
 }
 if checkRecord == true
 {
     //succesfull authenticate
 }
 else
 {
   //show the error message
 }
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass 5 strings ?